# Where to place custom format (.fmt) files when using MikTeX?

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9, format-files, mylatexformat

I have created my own `.fmt` file, but can't seem to find where to put it so that it is found by pdflatex. I am using the MikTeX distribution.

I have tried setting `TEXFORMATS` as an environment variable, as well as adding it to `texmfs/config/miktex/config/pdflatex.ini`. I also tried placing the `.fmt` file at various places in my local and the home `texmf` tree. I also tried to use the format tab in the MikTeX console and tried adding a `.ini` file to be compiled to a `.fmt` file there (which would of course be great if this could be done at the click of a button), but could not find out where to put this `.ini` file (I again tried various locations in both `texmf` trees).

But still, with none these approaches could `pdflatex` find my `.fmt` file (the `pdflatex.log` reads `The memory dump file could not be found.`, a `.log` file for the file itself (the one that I want to compile) is never generated). What am I doing wrong?

I am using `mylatexformat` with the following code:

```
%&mydocumentclass.fmt
\documentclass{mydocumentclass}
\endofdump

\begin{document}
  test text
\end{document}
```

I then compile that code using `pdftex -ini -jobname="mydocumentclass" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx mydocumentclass.tex`.

Comment: (I don't know whether a MWE or a copy of the `.fmt` file is needed for this question)

Comment: If you want to use the format tab and have an ini that can be used, put the `mypdflatex.ini` into a local texmf tree in `tex\latex\something` and don't forget to update the file name database.  I never installed a format manually, but my first try would be in a local texmf in `\miktex\data\le\pdftex` as that is the path miktex uses for the other formats.

Comment: Could the problem be that I am using the `mylatexformat` mechanism? I have added the code I use in the question.

Comment: Your second suggestion does not seem to work, and as your first suggestion is concerned, I can't figure out how to emulate `mylatexformat` behaviour when compiling the `.ini` file via `MikTeX`.

Comment: I tried something to the effect of `\scrollmode \input latex.ltx \input mylatexformat.ltx \documentclass{mydocumentclass} \endofdump \endinput` for the `.ini` file, but had no success.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to load mylatexformat in an ini. You know where the \dump should be in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success by just putting my `.fmt` files into `\miktex\data\le\pdftex` in the preinstalled `data` texmf tree instead of the `install` tree (thank you to Ulrike Fischer for the helpful comments). I found this by searching for the formats I built using the format tab.

I could not get the "building format from `.ini` file via MikTeX Console format tab" method to work, but as I have a working solution now, I don't really care to figure out the details there.

Edit:
After updating MikTeX I had to redo this process and found that before LaTeX could find the `.fmt` file (even when the`.fmt` file was placed in the correct spot), I had to have built a format with the same name at least once. After letting MikTeX build such a format and then replacing it again with my own `.fmt` file, everthing worked. I assume there is some kind of config that lists all the available formats and where MikTeX should look for them, but I could not find it.

Comment: If anyone knows why this (using the `data` tree instead of the `install` tree) works, please feel free to edit answer.